# Importing flat file

Tags: file, dbf, flat

I've got a db flat file(multi-dimensional table), with following structure:

```
AAA00010001something1something2
AAA00010002something3something4
..
AAA0001NNNNsomethingNsomethingN
AAA0002NNNNsomethingNsomethingN
..
AAANNNNNNNNsomethingNsomethingN
AABNNNNNNNNsomethingNsomethingN
..
ZZZNNNNNNNNsomethingNsomethingN
```

How to import/convert it into FoxPro dbf(table(s))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear. What would your DBF file look like? It's meaningless to just "convert it to dbf"; a DBF file is a database that has fields (columns), each of which have names, sizes and data types. What would this content represent? And where would each column begin and end? And what type value is it supposed to be? And what programming language are you asking for help with? Your question is entirely too vague to be answered here. You need to be more specific about what you're trying to do. (You can [edit] your question to provide more information.)

Comment: Agree with Ken, are you working with dBASE, Visual FoxPro directly?  Please edit original question with additional details.